# RegEx : (double)quoted strings

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using c# RegEx to search quoted strings in a script text.
I use this expression : `new Regex("\"((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\\"]*)*)\"")`, 
e.g `"((?:\\.|[^\\\"]*)*)"`
meanings to not take care of `\"` cases

This makes `RegEx.Matches` runs and never stops for some input strings.

Never mind this problem with .Net RegEx, I know my expression is not the best one.

Before, I used `(?<!\\)".*?(?<!\\)"` expression but it is not enough for `"\\"` input string.

The aim is to detect quoted strings before I analyze script codes.

Any one would suggest a good expression ?

It has to work for :

```
echo("Hello" + yourName + ", here is \"MyTest\"");
path = "\\" + file;
echo("path ends with \\");
```

*(beware, \ are strangely edited with this site)*

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please put the regex into it's own line and preceed it with four leading spaces? Elseway, Nobody can understand what you're actually trying to say us.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is matched using

```
"((?:[^\\"]|\\.)*)"
```

See http://www.ideone.com/JiJwa.

Comment: tested with http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx, your expression does not work with the given code in my question.